# Kids' SF chapterbook about Mars, with three-eyed Martian animals and hidden Old Martians

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, mars

Protagonists were Sally and Jim, ages 11 and 12 or thereabouts ("Jim, six and a half, and Sally, six" in Martian years) middle-class white suburban kids whose family moves to a Martian dome-city.

Previous colonists believe the highest Martian life-form is a three-eyed tortoise (possibly with some discussion of how Earthly animals' pituitary glands evolved from third eyes), but Jim and Sally discover a cute Martian cat and humanoid Old Martians. Illustrations include said animals, the dome city, caterpillar-tread domed rovers.

Probably from the 50s or 60s, early 70s at the latest? Paperback cover possibly yellow.

Comment: I think I remember this book; if so, I got it from a BookMobile around 1974 in the US.  I don't recall much more about it, except I think I remember that the city domes were made of plastic? (which isn't hugely important; I'm not sure why I'd remember such a trivial thing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it.  [Lost Race of Mars](http://www.papergreat.com/2014/10/scholastic-fest-1-lost-race-of-mars.html), by Robert Silverberg.  Definitely the book I was remembering, and it involves Martian 'kittens', and the character names are right.

Comment: Whoa! And here I thought I didn't get around to Silverberg till the 90s.

Comment: Same here!  Never would have connected him with this book.