# 70s/80s children's book about space colonist boy who realises by telepathy that the aliens are sentient

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I must have read this in the early 1980s in the UK; possibly a 1970s publication. It was a children's novella about a boy who's part of a human space colonist family on a planet inhabited by aliens that aren't thought to be sentient. I think the planet was kind of desert-y or cowboy movie-ish, and the aliens roamed about it like horses or tumbleweeds. The aliens might have been wheel-shaped? The boy learned to communicate with them by telepathy and then had to persuade adult society to be nicer to the aliens.

Comment: It's been awhile since I read it, but [Red Mars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/243911/20490) might fit the bill.

Comment: It isn't a close match, but one of Asimov's Space Ranger series has something of the sort. Animals that seem like dumb frogs are actually semi-intelligent and telepathic.  They send out a telepathic message to "feed me"  which  people can't help obeying.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Starr_and_the_Oceans_of_Venus#Plot_summary

Comment: This reminds me of one of the James Schmidt stories in his Hub Federation setting - not the Telzey Amberdon stories, but set in that universe. I can't think of the name of the story I'm thinking of, however.

Comment: Maybe "Hallucination" by Asimov?

Comment: One of my school teachers read out an excerpt from a similar story (80s UK), I suspect it was the same one.  The creatures were called "wheels" but the teacher explained they were animals, not actual wheels, I don't know if they were wheel-shaped.  I remember a scene where a friendly wheel excitedly rushed up to the protagonist and stopped, and a nearby adult was horrified and insisted "it charged you!".